# Is it possible for stockfish to tell that mate is in X moves, when mate is in X + Y moves?

Tags: engines, stockfish

I know that it is possible for a chess engine to evaluate a position as mate in X moves, when in fact there exist a mate in smaller number of moves. But can the reverse situation happen?

For example the engine evaluated a position as mate in 8 moves, but actually the best possible mate is in 9 moves (or 10 or 13).

To be more concrete the engine is stockfish.

Comment: Assuming Y>0, I suppose that would require some mistake in the programmation of the chess engine. Or you feeding it the position un-precisely, like not informing it that castling rights have been lost.

Comment: @Evargalo yes, assuming Y > 0, otherwise you and up with the example I described in the first paragraph. And yes, assuming there is no mistake in the engine (otherwise if you assume possible mistake, you can justify any evaluation)

Comment: @SalvadorDali Good question. The 2nd paragraph of phonon resolved it for me, it's funny how engines sometimes work like us :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible because, before Stockfish says it is Mate in 8, it views the position from the aspect of the losing side, i.e, the evaluation is the best that can be obtained by the losing side.

In other words, Mate in 8 is what happens if the losing side plays the possibly best defense. If the losing side plays sub-optimally, it could lose faster, but 8 moves is the longest possible postponement of Checkmate

Comment: I don't believe this is correct, however it's possible I'm wrong. What if stockfish makes a mistake because it prunes some possible responses that superficially seem worse but in fact lead to a slower checkmate?